# Is it safe to insert into Elasticsearch a JSON format string?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using the last Elasticsearch (v. 2.1.1).

My app offers a search engine when the users may search for the various products. I'm using Elasticsearch PHP Client to build the parameters for the search (the variable $params contains all info about index, type and query):

```
$params = [
 'index' => 'myindex',
 'type' => 'mytype',
];

$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['match']['ref'] = array("query" => 'Foo bar', "operator" => "and");
```

What I need is to save every search made by my users. I have found that the simplest way is:

Convert the $params array in JSON formatted string:

```
$output = array();
foreach($params['body'] as $v) {
$output[key($v)] = current($v);
}

$params_json = json_encode($output);
```

Now $params_json variable contains the JSON formatted string (the search params performed by user):

```
{"filtered":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"fulltext.phonetic":{"query":"Foo bar","operator":"and"}}}]}}},"ts":{"order":"desc"}}
```

Practically, we have there the so called USER INPUT, and as far I know we should never trust it, at least in the old world of MySQL database (yes, the famous sql injections).

So my question is - is it safe to save (or, more elastic friendly, index) such type of data (JSON formatted string with the USER INPUT) in Elasticsearch database?

The working solution I already applied is:

1) Create an index and apply this mapping (object type and disabled the field where we will insert the JSON string):

```
... query: { type: "object", enabled: false } ...
```

2) Insert JSON string in that field using script (it's required for make an upsert, it will insert if that record doesn't exists or will update if it's already there (update a counter (how many times that search was performed) for example):

```
$params2 = [
 'index' => 'searches',
 'type' => 'queries',
 'id' => md5($params_json),
 'body' => [
    'script' => 'ctx._source.counter += count',
    'params' => [
        'count' => 1
    ],
    'upsert' => [
        'query' => $params_json,
        'ts' => time(),
        'counter' => 1
    ]
 ]
];

$result = $this->db->update($params2);
```

If you have others solutions without using the script in Elasticsearch (you should know that the script is really dangerous and should be disabled if you don't know what you are doing).

Please post here your thoughts about this approach? Is it safe?

It works fine, I can use the data in JSON to use it later for perform the searches but the question is - is it really safe and if not why I should avoid it?

I don't want that some "script kiddie" will break the security of my app.

I will really appreciate if you will share your opinion about it.

Comment: Personally, I would simply save that JSON as a string, i.e. using `"type": "string"` instead of `"object"`. So you don't run any risks regarding scripting.

Comment: @Val thank you for your suggestion. I will set string type to that field.